# Flutter / Dart: Calling a method without double-dots (..)

Tags: flutter, dart

Can i write the following code differently, without using "double-dots" for calling a method:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => ManageCostCubit(fakeLocalRepository)..getAllCost(),

      child: MaterialApp(
```

Something like this is what i am looking for, but i get red underline in VS Code: "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found."

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) {
         ManageCostCubit(fakeLocalRepository); 
         context.read<ManageCostCubit>().getAllCost();
       },
      child: MaterialApp(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create: (context) => {
  var manageCostCubit = ManageCostCubit(fakeLocalRepository);
  manageCostCubit.getAllCost();
  return manageCostCubit;
}
```